# Calculating distance travelled from gps track points using python

Tags: python, time, gps, distance, haversine

I have this very silly question to ask. I have GPS track points for a journey like this:

```
863.3,2013-10-05T01:21:07Z,0,13.348841,77.686539  
863.3,2013-10-05T01:21:08Z,1,13.348841,77.686539  
863.3,2013-10-05T01:21:23Z,2,13.348708,77.686248  
861.1,2013-10-05T01:21:28Z,3,13.348647,77.686088  
867.0,2013-10-05T01:29:03Z,4,13.34732,77.682364
```

All I want is to find the distance traveled: should I only consider the first track point and the last track point? Or do I need to find the distance traveled between every track point?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about geometry.

Comment: It's up to you. The two concepts you are alluding to are [distance and displacement](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-1/Distance-and-Displacement). The length between first and last points are displacement, the sum of the lengths between each point is distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you parse your gps points, you need to extract the lat/lon points for each.  You could use the following formula adapted from [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to get the distances between each pair of points and add sum them for your total distance.

```
import math

def getDistance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):
    # This uses the haversine formula, which remains a good numberical computation,
    # even at small distances, unlike the Shperical Law of Cosines.
    # This method has ~0.3% error built in.
    R = 6371 # Radius of Earth in km

    dLat = math.radians(float(lat2) - float(lat1))
    dLon = math.radians(float(lon2) - float(lon1))
    lat1 = math.radians(float(lat1))
    lat2 = math.radians(float(lat2))

    a = math.sin(dLat/2) * math.sin(dLat/2) + \
        math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dLon/2) * math.sin(dLon/2)

    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))

    d = R * c * 0.621371 # Converting km to miles with "* 0.621371"

    return d
```

Note that this function returns your distances in miles, but you can keep things metric in (km) by removing the "* 0.621371" from the end.

Of course these are assuming great circle lines.  You're probably traveling some sort of network, so this will certainly not be real world accurate.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get an estimate of the distance travelled between the GPS track points you have, you definitely need to consider the distances between all consecutive points. More precisely, if you have N positions, you need to iterate over all positions you have and sum up the distance between each point P_i and P_i+1 (ordered by the time it has been recorded).

If you would only calculate the distance between the first and the last point, the result would not be of any meaning at all. Imagine a set of N points that have been recorded while moving a track that represents a large circle. The first and the last point would be almost the same, hence resulting in a very small distance, even though the total distance you travelled while moving in the circle is significantly larger.

However, be aware that summing up the distance between consecutive points will still only be an estimate of the total distance travelled. Depending on the resolution of your track (i.e., the frequency in wich the positions of your track have been submitted) the accuracy compared to the real distance may vary significantly.